# Calculate square's 3d rotation and position from it's dimension and pixel coordinates

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, image-processing

Let assume that I have a picture of a square table and I want to put 3d cube on top of it like this : 
[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwwbI.jpg)

and I have this information : [pixel coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN544.jpg)

How can I calculate the transformation matrix?
I believe that the answer is in the perspective coordinates but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Without more information I don’t believe that this is possible. You can come up with a camera-relative rotation by examining the vanishing points of the square’s sides, but without knowing something about the camera you can’t tell how far away it is.

Comment: Thank you for responding. What about the rotation only can I calculate it? since I have the pixel coordinates assuming that the camera-square distance = E.